# How to find total sum of an array then checking if its odd or even in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wrote the following code which works for cases with the array has more than one element. 
How could I make it work when the array consist of just one element?

The below works for [1,23,4,5] but not for [0], [2], [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zroPn.png)

```js
function oddOrEven(array) {
  var sum = array.reduce(function(acc, intialvalue) {
    return acc + intialvalue;
  });

  if (sum % 2 == 0) {
    return "even"
  } else {
    return "odd"
  }
}

console.log(oddOrEven([1,23,4,5]))
console.log(oddOrEven([0]))
console.log(oddOrEven([1]))
```

[image: Please check this screenshot]

Comment: Just do a check if the array length is 1, if so, return the value of that array. If not, do the rest of your code.

Comment: Please elaborate question because `[0], [2], [1]` are returning as expected

Comment: I've edited to include a snippet, but it seems to be working, perhaps I've interpreted  the `[0], [2], [1]` incorrectly?

Comment: `function oddOrEven(array) {
  var sum = array.reduce((acc, intialvalue) => acc + intialvalue);
  return (sum % 2 == 0) ? "even" : "odd"
}`

Comment: @OliverRadini - maybe he is using number directly, not using array - `console.log(oddOrEven(1))`

Comment: I am doing a Kata challenge, I have just attached a image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRl06.png ...It working for all but edge cases which contains one element in an array

Answer (score 5):

As the error says, you must have an initial value, 0 in our case.

```js
function oddOrEven(array) {
  var sum = array.reduce(function(acc, intialvalue) {
    return acc + intialvalue;
  }, 0);

  if (sum % 2 == 0) {
    return "even"
  } else {
    return "odd"
  }
}

console.log(oddOrEven([1,23,4,5]))
console.log(oddOrEven([0]))
console.log(oddOrEven([1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

No initial value means you need to set the initial value of the reduce funtion as 0.

```
function oddOrEven(array) {
  var sum = array.reduce(function(acc, value) {
    return acc + intialValue;
  }, 0); // <- set the reduce functions initial value

  if (sum % 2 == 0) {
    return "even";
  } else {
    return "odd";
  }
}
```

You can clean this code up a little by re-writing it as

```
const oddOrEven = (array) => {
  const sum = array.reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);

  return (sum % 2 == 0) ? "even" : "odd";
};
```

Comment: Hi VtoCorleone, whats the name of the following operator -->(sum % 2 == 0) ? "even" : "odd";///<--

Comment: @jon Its called [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, you will need to pass an initial value to [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

As an alternate solution, you could just count whether there are are an even or number of odd elements in the array.

```js
const oddOrEven = (array) => array.reduce((a, i) => i % 2 ^ a, 1) ? "even" : "odd"; 

console.log(oddOrEven([1,23,4,5]))
console.log(oddOrEven([0]))
console.log(oddOrEven([1]))
```

Consider the following truth table:

```
x    y    | x+y
----------|-----
even even | even
even odd  | odd
odd  even | odd
odd  odd  | even
```

Answer (score 2):

Give an initial value to your reduce call. You could also handle the case of an empty array, here I return undefinef:

```js
const oddOrEven = arr => arr.length
  ? arr.reduce((sum, x) => sum + x, 0) % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'
  : undefined;

console.log(oddOrEven([1, 23, 4, 5]))
console.log(oddOrEven([0]))
console.log(oddOrEven([1]))
console.log(oddOrEven([]))
```

Comment: Hi jo_va, what is the name of this  -->A ? "even" : "odd" <-- operator?

Comment: @jon, this is a ternary operator, the condition is before the question mark, if it is true, the part before the semicolon is evaluated, otherwise, the part to the right of the semicolon is evaluated

Answer (score 1):

[**Bitwise &**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_AND)) can be used to check even and odd

```js
function oddOrEven(array) {
  var sum = array.reduce((op, inp) => op + inp, 0);
  return sum & 1 ? 'odd' : 'even' 
}

console.log(oddOrEven([1,23,4,5]))
console.log(oddOrEven([0]))
console.log(oddOrEven([1]))
```

For the one-line lovers

```js
const oddOrEven = a => a.reduce((o,i) => o + i, 0) & 1 ? 'odd' : 'even' 

console.log(oddOrEven([1,23,4,5]))
console.log(oddOrEven([0]))
console.log(oddOrEven([1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
whether the sum of array elements is even or odd and if array is empty its even.. 
function evenandOdd(arr) {
    let sumofarr = 0;
            for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sumofarr = sumofarr + arr[i];
        }  //return sumofarr;
        if(sumofarr % 2 == 0 || arr.length == 0) 
            return 'even'; 
            else return 'odd';
} 
console.log(evenandOdd([-102, -1, 3]));
```